# Responding to Login Succeeded for Blazor Web Assembly App and Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, blazor, blazor-client-side

I have a Blazor Web Assembly App that successfully authenticates against Azure AD B2C. Whenever the user successfully authenticates, or logs in, I want to fetch some additional profile information from another service/database.

I feel/think the answer is somewhere in this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/blazor/webassembly/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-3.1, but for the life of me, everything I try fails.

Wondering if anyone else has tried this and has been successful?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contacting the Blazor team, this is what they recommended https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/blazor/webassembly/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-3.1#customize-the-user.